# React Native Error Failures - nodejs-lts (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs-lts\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, installation

I am encountering this error when installing React Native on Windows device.It installed one package but the other package is not installed.

`choco install -y nodejs-lts microsoft-openjdk11`

I have a problem with this command.
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZu9V.png)

I made the updates, changed a few security-related settings, but the error did not change.